# Error: No Contract deployed with name NftMarketplace

Tags: solidity, blockchain, javascript

I am following Patrick Collins BlockChain course and Currently I am facing this error whenever I try to test my nft marketplace contract.

My files:

NftMarketplace.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

error NftMarketPlace__PriceMustBeAboveZero();
error NftMarketPlace__NotApprovedForMarketplace();
error NftMarketplace__AlreadyListed(address nftAddress, uint256 tokenId);
error NftMarketPlace__notOwner();
error NftMarketPlace__NotListed(address nftAddress, uint256 tokenId);
error NftMarketPlace__PriceNotMet(address nftAddress, uint256 tokenId, uint256 price);
error NftMarketPlace__noProceeds();
error NftMarketPlace__TransferFailed();

contract NftMarketplace is ReentrancyGuard {
    struct Listing {
        uint256 price;
        address seller;
    }

    event ItemListed(
        address indexed seller,
        address indexed nftAddress,
        uint256 indexed tokenId,
        uint256 price
    );

    event ItemBought(
        address indexed buyer,
        address indexed nftAddress,
        uint256 indexed tokenId,
        uint256 price
    );

    event ItemCanceled(address indexed seller, address indexed nftAddress, uint256 indexed tokenId);

    //NFT Contract address->NFT TokenID->Listing
    mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => Listing)) private s_listings;

    //Seller address ->Amount earned
    mapping(address => uint256) private s_proceeds;

    //Modifiers
    modifier notListed(
        address nftAddress,
        uint256 tokenId,
        address owner
    ) {
        Listing memory listing = s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId];
        if (listing.price > 0) {
            revert NftMarketplace__AlreadyListed(nftAddress, tokenId);
        }
        _;
    }
    modifier isOwner(
        address nftAddress,
        uint256 tokenId,
        address spender
    ) {
        IERC721 nft = IERC721(nftAddress);
        address owner = nft.ownerOf(tokenId);
        if (spender != owner) {
            revert NftMarketPlace__notOwner();
        }
        _;
    }

    modifier isListed(address nftAddress, uint256 tokenId) {
        Listing memory listing = s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId];
        if (listing.price <= 0) {
            revert NftMarketPlace__NotListed(nftAddress, tokenId);
        }
        _;
    }

    //Main functions
    /*
     * @notice Method for listing your NFT on the marketplace
     * @pram nftAddress: Address of the NFT
     * *@pram tokenId: The token ID of the NFT
     * @pram price: sale price of the listed NFT
     * @dev Tecnically,we could have the contract be escrow for the NFTs
     * *but this people can still hold their NFTs when listed.
     */

    function listItem(
        address nftAddress,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 price
    ) external notListed(nftAddress, tokenId, msg.sender) isOwner(nftAddress, tokenId, msg.sender) {
        if (price <= 0) {
            revert NftMarketPlace__PriceMustBeAboveZero();
        }

        IERC721 nft = IERC721(nftAddress);
        if (nft.getApproved(tokenId) != address(this)) {
            revert NftMarketPlace__NotApprovedForMarketplace();
        }
        s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId] = Listing(price, msg.sender);
        emit ItemListed(msg.sender, nftAddress, tokenId, price);
    }

    function buyItem(
        address nftAddress,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) external payable nonReentrant isListed(nftAddress, tokenId) {
        Listing memory listedItem = s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId];
        if (msg.value < listedItem.price) {
            revert NftMarketPlace__PriceNotMet(nftAddress, tokenId, listedItem.price);
        }
        //sending the money to the user ❌
        //Have them withdraw the money ✅
        s_proceeds[listedItem.seller] = s_proceeds[listedItem.seller] + msg.value;
        delete (s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId]);
        IERC721(nftAddress).safeTransferFrom(listedItem.seller, msg.sender, tokenId);
        //check to make sure the NFT was transfered.
        emit ItemBought(msg.sender, nftAddress, tokenId, listedItem.price);
    }

    function cancelListing(
        address nftAddress,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) external isOwner(nftAddress, tokenId, msg.sender) isListed(nftAddress, tokenId) {
        delete (s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId]);
        emit ItemCanceled(msg.sender, nftAddress, tokenId);
    }

    function updateListing(
        address nftAddress,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 newPrice
    ) external isListed(nftAddress, tokenId) isOwner(nftAddress, tokenId, msg.sender) {
        s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId].price = newPrice;
        emit ItemListed(msg.sender, nftAddress, tokenId, newPrice);
    }

    function withdrawProceeds() external {
        uint256 proceeds = s_proceeds[msg.sender];
        if (proceeds <= 0) {
            revert NftMarketPlace__noProceeds();
        }
        s_proceeds[msg.sender] = 0;
        (bool success, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: proceeds}("");
        if (!success) {
            revert NftMarketPlace__TransferFailed();
        }
    }

    //Getter Functions

    function getListing(
        address nftAddress,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) external view returns (Listing memory) {
        return s_listings[nftAddress][tokenId];
    }

    function geProceeds(address seller) external view returns (uint256) {
        return s_proceeds[seller];
    }
}
```

01-deploy-nft-marketplace.js

```
const { developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

    let args = []

    const nftMarketplace = await deploy("NftMarketplace", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })
    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("verifying..")
        await verify(nftMarketplace.includes, args)
    }
    log("-------------------------")

    module.exports.tags = ["all", "nftmarketplace"]
}
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

    let args = []

    const nftMarketplace = await deploy("NftMarketplace", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })
    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("verifying..")
        await verify(nftMarketplace.includes, args)
    }
    log("-------------------------")

    module.exports.tags = ["all", "nftmarketplace"]
}
```

NftMarketplace.test.js

```
const { network, deployments, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("Nft Marketplace Unit Tests", function () {
          let nftMarketplace, nftMarketplaceContract, basicNft, basicNftContract
          const PRICE = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1")
          const TOKEN_ID = 0

          beforeEach(async () => {
              accounts = await ethers.getSigners() // could also do with getNamedAccounts
              deployer = accounts[0]
              user = accounts[1]
              await deployments.fixture(["all"])
              nftMarketplaceContract = await ethers.getContract("NftMarketplace")
              nftMarketplace = nftMarketplaceContract.connect(deployer)
              basicNftContract = await ethers.getContract("BasicNft")
              basicNft = await basicNftContract.connect(deployer)
              await basicNft.mintNft()
              await basicNft.approve(nftMarketplaceContract.address, TOKEN_ID)
          })

          describe("listItem", function () {
              it("emits an event after listing an item", async function () {
                  expect(await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)).to.emit(
                      "ItemListed"
                  )
              })
              it("exclusively items that haven't been listed", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  const error = `AlreadyListed("${basicNft.address}", ${TOKEN_ID})`
                  //   await expect(
                  //       nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  //   ).to.be.revertedWith("AlreadyListed")
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith(error)
              })
              it("exclusively allows owners to list", async function () {
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplaceContract.connect(user)
                  await basicNft.approve(user.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NotOwner")
              })
              it("needs approvals to list item", async function () {
                  await basicNft.approve(ethers.constants.AddressZero, TOKEN_ID)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NotApprovedForMarketplace")
              })
              it("Updates listing with seller and price", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  const listing = await nftMarketplace.getListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  assert(listing.price.toString() == PRICE.toString())
                  assert(listing.seller.toString() == deployer.address)
              })
          })
          describe("cancelListing", function () {
              it("reverts if there is no listing", async function () {
                  const error = `NotListed("${basicNft.address}", ${TOKEN_ID})`
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.cancelListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith(error)
              })
              it("reverts if anyone but the owner tries to call", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplaceContract.connect(user)
                  await basicNft.approve(user.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.cancelListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NotOwner")
              })
              it("emits event and removes listing", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  expect(await nftMarketplace.cancelListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)).to.emit(
                      "ItemCanceled"
                  )
                  const listing = await nftMarketplace.getListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  assert(listing.price.toString() == "0")
              })
          })
          describe("buyItem", function () {
              it("reverts if the item isnt listed", async function () {
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.buyItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NotListed")
              })
              it("reverts if the price isnt met", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.buyItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("PriceNotMet")
              })
              it("transfers the nft to the buyer and updates internal proceeds record", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplaceContract.connect(user)
                  expect(
                      await nftMarketplace.buyItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, { value: PRICE })
                  ).to.emit("ItemBought")
                  const newOwner = await basicNft.ownerOf(TOKEN_ID)
                  const deployerProceeds = await nftMarketplace.getProceeds(deployer.address)
                  assert(newOwner.toString() == user.address)
                  assert(deployerProceeds.toString() == PRICE.toString())
              })
          })
          describe("updateListing", function () {
              it("must be owner and listed", async function () {
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.updateListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NotListed")
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplaceContract.connect(user)
                  await expect(
                      nftMarketplace.updateListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("NotOwner")
              })
              it("updates the price of the item", async function () {
                  const updatedPrice = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.2")
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  expect(
                      await nftMarketplace.updateListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, updatedPrice)
                  ).to.emit("ItemListed")
                  const listing = await nftMarketplace.getListing(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID)
                  assert(listing.price.toString() == updatedPrice.toString())
              })
          })
          describe("withdrawProceeds", function () {
              it("doesn't allow 0 proceed withdrawls", async function () {
                  await expect(nftMarketplace.withdrawProceeds()).to.be.revertedWith("NoProceeds")
              })
              it("withdraws proceeds", async function () {
                  await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplaceContract.connect(user)
                  await nftMarketplace.buyItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, { value: PRICE })
                  nftMarketplace = nftMarketplaceContract.connect(deployer)

                  const deployerProceedsBefore = await nftMarketplace.getProceeds(deployer.address)
                  const deployerBalanceBefore = await deployer.getBalance()
                  const txResponse = await nftMarketplace.withdrawProceeds()
                  const transactionReceipt = await txResponse.wait(1)
                  const { gasUsed, effectiveGasPrice } = transactionReceipt
                  const gasCost = gasUsed.mul(effectiveGasPrice)
                  const deployerBalanceAfter = await deployer.getBalance()

                  assert(
                      deployerBalanceAfter.add(gasCost).toString() ==
                          deployerProceedsBefore.add(deployerBalanceBefore).toString()
                  )
              })
          })
      })
```

I run this command: yarn hardhat test

and get this error:

yarn run v1.22.15
warning package.json: No license field
$ /home/shawon/hh-fcc/hardhat-nft-marketplace-fcc/node_modules/.bin/hardhat test

Nft Marketplace Unit Tests
listItem
1) "before each" hook for "emits an event after listing an item"

0 passing (597ms)
1 failing

1. Nft Marketplace Unit Tests
   "before each" hook for "emits an event after listing an item":
   Error: No Contract deployed with name NftMarketplace
   at Object.getContract (node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:447:11)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
   at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
   at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
   at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
   at Context. (test/unit/NftMarketplace.test.js:17:40)

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
**